# Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$ Such that $\frac{1}{x}+y+z = \frac{1}{y}+x+z = \frac{1}{z}+x+y=3 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Find $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$ Such that :
$$\frac{1}{x}+y+z = \frac{1}{y}+x+z = \frac{1}{z}+x+y =3$$

**My Attempt:**
I’ve turned this into a system of equations :
$$\cases{\frac{1}{x}+y+z =3 \\ \frac{1}{y}+x+z =3 \\ \frac{1}{z}+x+y=3 } \iff \cases{1+xy+zx=3x \\1+xy+zy=3y \\1+xz+yz=3z}$$
Multiplying some equations by $-1$ and adding them together we get:
$$z(y-x)=3(y-x)\iff z=3$$
Notice that $y\ne x$.

You can play a little bit with $x,y$ ’s values, you will end up with :
$$(x,y,z) \in \{(3,\frac{-1}{3},3), (-3, \frac{1}{3},3)\}$$
**Edit:** *user* pointed out in comments that the first triple of my solution doesn’t work in all cases, but i don’t know why.

And the values of $x,y,z$ Can swap places because of the symmetry in the equations.

My question is what would happen if $x=y$.

And there is one more thing to notice is that one of the obvious solutions is $$x=y=z=1$$

Thank you.

Comment: $z(y-x)=3(y-z)\iff z=3\text{ or }y=x$.  Similarly the others, so consider all possible combinations.

Comment: Hint: $z = \dfrac{1}{3 - 2x}$ if $x = y$.

Comment: $(0.5,0.5,0.5)$ is a solution as well.

Comment: The first triple of your solution  does not work.

Comment: How can we get this solution- @garondal

Comment: @yassir: Assume $x=y=z$ and then solve $\frac{1}{x}+x+x=3$ which yields $x=1$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If the domain of problem was $ \mathbb{R}^+ $ then the problem is very instructive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given such $x,y,z\in\Bbb{R}$, in particular you have
$$\frac1x+y+z=\frac1y+x+z,$$
and hence also $x-\tfrac1x=y-\tfrac1y$. By symmetry we see that
$$x-\frac1x=y-\frac1y=z-\frac1z=c,$$
for some constant $c$, and so $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all roots of
$$T^2-cT-1=0.\tag{1}$$
A quadratic polynomial has at most two real roots, so without loss of generality we have $x=y$. We distinguish two cases:

1. If $x=y=z$, then we get the identity
   $$\frac1x+x+x=3,$$
   and hence $2x^2-3x+1=0$. This quadratic factors as
   $$2x^2-3x+1=(2x-1)(x-1),$$
   yielding the two solutions $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ and $(x,y,z)=(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12)$.
2. If $z\neq x$, then also $z\neq y$ and so $xz=yz=-1$ because $x$ and $z$ are distinct roots of the quadratic $(1)$. Then from
   $$\frac1z+x+y=3,$$
   we find that also
   $$3z=1+xz+yz=1+(-1)+(-1)=-1,$$
   which shows that $z=-\tfrac13$ and hence $x=y=3$. This yields the three solutions
   $$(x,y,z)=(3,3,-\tfrac13),\qquad (x,y,z)=(3,-\tfrac13,3),\qquad(x,y,z)=(-\tfrac13,3,3).$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x = y$,
$$\dfrac{1}{z} + x + y = 2x + 1/z = 3 \implies z = \dfrac{1}{3-2x}$$
Hence $x + 1/y + z = x + 1/x + 1/(3-2x) = 3$. Multiply this term by $x(3-2x)$ for $x \notin \{0, 3/2\}$ and after rearranging you will get the cubic equation
$$2x^3 - 9x^2 + 10x - 3 =(x-1)(2x^2 - 7x + 3) =  0$$
$\implies x = 1$, $x = 3$ or $ x = 0.5$.

Comment: You shoud get $-2x^3+9x^2-10x+3=0$ (with solutions $x=1,0.5,3$) and not $7x^2-11x+4=0$.

Comment: Thank you! I did not do this on paper, I apologise for the incorrect answer.

Comment: @garondal edited